# Matching and pulling values

Tags: excel

I've simplified a problem, where I have a sheet with 80,000+ rows and another sheet that is an index of sorts:

[image]

I need to structure a formula where, I need to pull the value in the second table, for `a` it would be `1` and so forth into the first table. I've tried:

`=IF(VLOOKUP(A2, Table1, 1, 0), E2, "")` but I get an #N/A error. I am not sure how to go about structuring this formula in a different way. I need to look up the value in the first Table, see if the value exists in the second table, and if it does, pull the corresponding value back into the first table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming:**

- your first table is in **A:B**
- your second table is in **D:E**

You can use this on B2 and drag:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E:E,MATCH(A2,D:D,0)),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A3,$I$3:$J$8,2,FALSE),"")
```

**Results**

[image]